# Separating factors into facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I would like to have factors separated by facet, as shown in Hadley's ggplot2 book pp. 154, but my code instead includes all factors in each facet. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
tw %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Likes, y = PlayerName)) + 
  ylab("Players") + xlab("Likes per Tweet") + 
  ggtitle("Engagement per Player") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#5DADE2", "#333333", "#A569BD")) +
  facet_grid(Sport ~., space = "free") +
  geom_point()
```

Where sample of `tw` is as follows:

```
tw <- structure(list(PlayerName = structure(c(6L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
15L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 15L, 12L, 
8L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 5L, 15L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 
11L, 11L, 14L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 
15L, 12L, 6L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 
10L, 13L, 10L, 6L, 14L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 
6L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 
15L, 12L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 13L, 12L, 8L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 
11L, 9L), .Label = c("Chris Paul", "Dwayne Wade", "Jeremy Lin", 
"LeBron James", "Steph Curry", "J.J. Watt", "Odell Beckham Jr", 
"Richard Sherman", "Rob Gronkowski", "Russell Wilson", "Cristiano Ronaldo", 
"Gareth Bale", "Mesut Ozil", "Neymar Jr", "Paul Pogba"), class = "factor"), 
    Sport = c("Football", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Basketball", 
    "Basketball", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Basketball", 
    "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", 
    "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Football", "Soccer", "Basketball", 
    "Basketball", "Basketball", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", 
    "Basketball", "Basketball", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Football", 
    "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Basketball", 
    "Football", "Football", "Basketball", "Soccer", "Football", 
    "Football", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Soccer", "Soccer", 
    "Football", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Football", 
    "Basketball", "Basketball", "Football", "Soccer", "Soccer", 
    "Football", "Football", "Soccer", "Football", "Football", 
    "Soccer", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Basketball", "Soccer", 
    "Basketball", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Football", "Football", 
    "Football", "Basketball", "Football", "Soccer", "Basketball", 
    "Football", "Soccer", "Football", "Basketball", "Basketball", 
    "Soccer", "Basketball", "Football", "Football", "Soccer", 
    "Soccer", "Soccer", "Basketball", "Football", "Football", 
    "Basketball", "Soccer", "Soccer", "Football", "Soccer", "Soccer", 
    "Soccer", "Soccer", "Football"), Likes = c(644L, 15369L, 
    656L, 758L, 752L, 10776L, 1838L, 4557L, 728L, 7100L, 7506L, 
    7907L, 1933L, 32945L, 1619L, 9450L, 7241L, 1154L, 442L, 5315L, 
    2300L, 7300L, 2500L, 6700L, 7778L, 8454L, 1600L, 3500L, 1615L, 
    7296L, 647L, 3753L, 13887L, 22775L, 13000L, 11000L, 1600L, 
    1400L, 948L, 933L, 6904L, 3100L, 104L, 12000L, 31200L, 13700L, 
    2674L, 16891L, 1800L, 27629L, 56053L, 6257L, 12000L, 1600L, 
    2400L, 3900L, 275L, 6208L, 8300L, 3900L, 1200L, 6500L, 1900L, 
    18000L, 2200L, 9522L, 95L, 800L, 6406L, 14000L, 4976L, 12000L, 
    1200L, 3000L, 1000L, 25000L, 741L, 9761L, 12000L, 559L, 2079L, 
    541L, 1129L, 4389L, 2197L, 34000L, 1200L, 1900L, 2222L, 1890L, 
    26767L, 2452L, 651L, 7300L, 3300L, 3823L, 4941L, 215L, 13000L, 
    11994L, 926L, 11946L, 561L)), row.names = c(194L, 529L, 902L, 
925L, 794L, 295L, 677L, 366L, 828L, 960L, 291L, 390L, 378L, 517L, 
310L, 578L, 293L, 678L, 238L, 635L, 713L, 736L, 928L, 946L, 281L, 
303L, 793L, 753L, 349L, 430L, 89L, 649L, 541L, 527L, 987L, 743L, 
804L, 140L, 48L, 894L, 426L, 71L, 227L, 1026L, 501L, 861L, 329L, 
595L, 186L, 393L, 523L, 461L, 776L, 242L, 887L, 758L, 171L, 429L, 
937L, 57L, 7L, 432L, 21L, 133L, 934L, 675L, 725L, 795L, 583L, 
779L, 467L, 1007L, 49L, 185L, 106L, 766L, 158L, 443L, 780L, 143L, 
321L, 229L, 840L, 872L, 600L, 769L, 260L, 63L, 372L, 670L, 492L, 
830L, 1L, 160L, 798L, 441L, 660L, 221L, 1005L, 478L, 344L, 526L, 
114L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("PlayerName", "Sport", 
"Likes"))
```

Here's the plot:
[image]

Comment: Do you want `scales = "free"`?

Comment: Take a look at [ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html) for `facet_grid()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `scales = "free"` instead of `space = "free"` in the call to `facet_grid()` I do get

[image]

Is it this what you'd expect?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tw, aes(x = Likes, y = PlayerName)) + 
  ylab("Players") + xlab("Likes per Tweet") + 
  ggtitle("Engagement per Player") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#5DADE2", "#333333", "#A569BD")) +
  facet_grid(Sport ~., scales = "free") +
  geom_point()
```